# combining number of images using matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I am trying to combine number of images in matlab. The number of combined images is up to four. I want them to be combined based on the concept of layers (as in photoshop) not to be concatenated together. This means that the size of the resulted image will be the same as the size of each combined image. Is there a matlab function that does that task properly?

Comment: Layers are just that, layers. If all images are the same size, what you will see in the combined image is just the top layer (i.e., the last image) in case there's no transparency. Now, I assume you'd want to combine them by multiplying, adding, subtracting, or other such operation? If yes, which operation(s) specifically?

Comment: Actually I was thinking of this idea to help me in the segmentation of medical tissue images. 
The idea is similar to the concept of layers in flash (or photoshop). For example  you first add background image (e.g. an image of a sea)on a separate layer, above this layer you add another layer containing objects(e.g. a ship), and above those two layers you can add another layer containing stars for examples. The final result(when having the swf file) is a single image that contains all objects that are all visible since they are located at different locations(with no transparency applied).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img1 = imread...
img2 = imread...
img3 = imread...
img4 = imread...

combined_img(:,1) = img1;
combined_img(:,2) = img2;
combined_img(:,3) = img3;
combined_img(:,4) = img4;
```

Now you have a 4 layered image which you can access by 3rd index of combined_img.
The following command will show the first image:

```
imshow(combined_img(:,1));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will try the code. Hoping to have the result that I want.

Comment: I assume the images are gray level images. So I mean they have only two dimension. Maybe you should give some information about images you want to use.

Comment: yes the images are in gray level, I have tried the code but it did not work.

Comment: Please tell me which part did not work? What do you expect to happen, before you can say it worked?

Comment: when applying the code I got the following error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: Your images are in different size.

Answer (score 0):

This does something like you describe:

```
function imgLayers


    % initialize figure
    figure(1), clf, hold on

    % just some random image (included with Matlab) to server
    % as the background
    img{1,1} = imresize(imread('westconcordaerial.png'), 4);    
    img{1,2} = [0 0];

    % rotate the image and discolor it to create another image
    img{2,1} = uint8(imresize(imrotate(img{1}, +12), 0.3)/2.5);
    img{2,2} = [150 20];

    % and another image
    img{3,1} = uint8(imresize(imrotate(img{1}, -15), 0.5)*2.5);
    img{3,2} = [450 80];

    % show the stacked image
    imshow(stack_image(img));

    %% create new image, based on several layers

    function newImg = stack_image(imgs)

        % every image contained at a cell index (ii) is placed 
        % on top of all the previous ones (0:ii-1)

        rows = cellfun(@(x)size(x,1),imgs(:,1));
        cols = cellfun(@(x)size(x,2),imgs(:,1));

        % initialize new image        
        newImg = zeros(max(rows(:)), max(cols(:)), 3, 'uint8');

        % traverse the stack
        for ii = 1:size(imgs,1)

            layer  = imgs{ii,1};
            offset = imgs{ii,2};

            newImg( offset(1)+(1:rows(ii)), offset(2)+(1:cols(ii)), :) = layer;

        end   
    end   

end
```

Take care though -- there's not enough bound checks etc. So you'll have to do a bit of developing yourself. But it should be enough to get you started :)

Comment: Thanks for understanding the idea I've described. I will try to understand the code above and make it applicable for the case I have.